# Browser can't show my cookie although I added it right before

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm adding a cookie in my console with `document.cookie = "newCookie=newValue"`.
Now I'm reading the cookie with `document.cookie`. But somehow the recently added Cookie don't appears.

I think there is something wrong with the way i'm reading the cookies out, because the console returns `''` (I guess that means I don't have any cookies stored)

[image: My Chrome Console]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you have to add `path` and `domain`...
This worked for me on the chrome console while viewing mozilla.org:

```
document.cookie
'' // response:empty

document.cookie='yourname=yourvalue;path=/;domain=mozilla.org'
'yourname=yourvalue;path=/;domain=mozilla.org' // response: input string

document.cookie
'yourname=yourvalue' // response: cookie name and value
```

More details here: [MDN Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)